# Passing multiple variables in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql, parameters

Currently I'm using

```
WHERE m.TCompany in ('&TCompany')
```

I enter in a code like `(C001)` and I get those results. But when I enter `(C001,C002)` I get no results.

What am I missing? How can I get multiple results for parameters entered?

Comment: Just because your parameter captains a comma (,) that DOES NOT make is a list, it's just a single string that happens to contain a comma.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. since 'C001,C002' is not a value in the column.  How do I get both values?

Comment: Perhaps this Q&A will help. [How can I use an array variable inside the IN operator for Oracle SQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141325/how-can-i-use-an-array-variable-inside-the-in-operator-for-oracle-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You are sending Oracle s single string that you wish to use as multiple values. Since Oracle has NO WAY of knowing that, you have to set it up. Meaning you have to separate the string. It's not however that complicated.

```
-- parse string demo
with parm as 
    (select '&par_value' pv from dual)
   , col_list as   
     ( select regexp_substr(pv,'[^,]+', 1, level) val from parm
       connect by regexp_substr(pv, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
     )
Select * from col_list;
```

Now for your particular case use the same parse functionality but put in into your where clause.

```
with parm as 
    (select '&par_value' pv from dual)
   , col_list as   
     ( select regexp_substr(pv,'[^,]+', 1, level) val from parm
       connect by regexp_substr(pv, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
     )
Select 
   <your select> 
where 
WHERE m.TCompany in (select val from col_list);
```

Comment: Thank you Belayer! This does work however it slows down the query. pulling both codes took 45mins. while pulling code 1 took mins and the 2nd was 4.5mins.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, maybe somewhat simpler:

```
SQL> select deptno, ename, job, sal
  2  from emp e join table(sys.odcivarchar2list(&jobs_list)) j
  3               on j.column_value = e.job;
Enter value for jobs_list: 'CLERK', 'MANAGER'
old   2: from emp e join table(sys.odcivarchar2list(&jobs_list)) j
new   2: from emp e join table(sys.odcivarchar2list('CLERK', 'MANAGER')) j

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
        20 SMITH      CLERK            800
        20 JONES      MANAGER         2975
        30 BLAKE      MANAGER         2850
        10 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
        20 ADAMS      CLERK           1100
        30 JAMES      CLERK            950
        10 MILLER     CLERK           1300

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks. You're saying that I need to put possible values their own table which is the sys.odcivarchar2list from your example?

Comment: You're welcome. No; my example shows that - when you're prompted to enter values for JOB_LIST (in my example), you should do so. As jobs are strings, they have to be enclosed into single quotes. If you put that into sys.odcivarchar2list, no problem either, but - I thought you want to enter those values manually each time you run the query - that's why I used a variable.